# Parse Cloud Code - afterSave

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm writing an `afterSave` function for my "likes" class and would also like to write an `afterSave` function for my "post" class. In my "likes" function I query for the liked post and then increment the likes column in the post object, consequently saving the post object.

What happens is when I like a post, the `afterSave` is called, queries for the post, increments it, saves it, and then the `afterSave` for my "post" class is called and a never ending sequence is created - "like" -> "post" -> "like" -> "post".

```
// Increment Counter
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("likes", function(request) {
                  var like = request.object.get("like");

                  var query = new Parse.Query("post");
                  query.get(request.object.get("post").id, {
                            success: function(post) {
                                post.increment("likes", 1);
                            }
                            post.save();
                            response.success("Updated Count");
                            },
                            error: function(error) {
                            response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
                            }
                        });
            });


Parse.Cloud.afterSave("post", function(request) {
     // Gets called after post.save(); 
     // Only should be called after new object
});
```

I would like the "likes" function and "post" function to only be called if a new obect is created. Not an update. And I don't want to create a custom function, and make the client side pass excess data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseObject.existed()` [Parse JavaScript API Docs.](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html)

`if(!request.object.existed())`.